# UID is the Group Owner on Windows / Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, mount, permissions, users

I have an external hard drive which both Ubuntu and Microsoft Windows can access (I'm pretty sure I used FAT or something). Anyway at the command prompt:

`ls -l` on the root level of the hard-drive.

What's weird is the owner is my Ubuntu user called `ub_user` and the group permissions are a random UID that doesn't resolve...

So I thought I could fix it by doing a `chown -R ub_user:ub_user *` on the hard drive and now `ub_user` has group permissions as well as the weird UID.

Super confused. Didn't know there could be multiple group ownership of a file.

Is this coming from Windows?

Is there any way for me to get rid of the random UID users? Should I or will it break everything?

Example line:

`ll Whiplash.mp4`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 ub_user ub_user 1767846558 Oct 22 2015 Whiplash.mp4`

What is 1767846558?

Comment: Can you post an example `ll` line? I'm not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: By the way: if you *did* use FAT, then the owner metadata is fake anyway. FAT has no concept of file owner; after all, it was created for operating systems that don't even have a concept of users. You can tell the filesystem driver when you mount the filesystem which user and group it should report to the OS; typically it will "pretend" all files are owned by the user who mounted the filesystem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the following:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ub_user ub_user 1767846558 Oct 22 2015 Whiplash.mp4
```

`1767846558` is not a weird UID. It's the file size.

Answer (score 3):

Files in (most) Linux filesystems have only one owning group/user.

As mentioned in your question, the following line can be parsed:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ub_user ub_user 1767846558 Oct 22 2015 Whiplash.mp4
```

- `-rw-r--r--`: File, owner had read/write, all others have read-only.
- `1`: The file has only one link (itself) attached to it.
- `ub_user`: The file is owned by the user `ub_user`.
- `ub_user`: The file is owned by the group `ub_user`.
- `1767846558`: The file is 1767846558 bytes in size.
- `Oct 22 2015`: The file was made on October 22, 2015.
- `Whiplash.mp4`: The file is called `Whiplash.mp4`.

If you instead call `ls -lh` on the file, you'll notice that your output would read something similar to:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ub_user ub_user 1.7G Oct 22 2015 Whiplash.mp4
```

Reflecting the fact that the file is about 1.7 GB in size.